# How to get values of an array into separate rows in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in which a columns has an Array.

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ["a", "b"] |
| 2 | ["a", "b", "c"] |

I am using a query that is given below.

```
select JSON_EXTRACT(t.date, '$') as id from table1 t where t.id = 1;
```

This gives result as the complete array, if I change the parameter like `'$[0]'` then I get value at 0 index.

How can I get result as follow : i.e (all the array values in separate row)

| result |
| --- |
| "a" |
| "b" |

Comment: Which version of mysql are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    data JSON
);

INSERT INTO mytable (id, data) VALUES (1, '["a", "b"]');
INSERT INTO mytable (id, data) VALUES (2, '["a", "b", "c"]');

SELECT T.id
      ,data.value
FROM mytable T
INNER JOIN JSON_TABLE
(
  T.data,
  "$[*]"
  COLUMNS(
    Value varchar(50) PATH "$"
  )
) data;
```

[image]